# How to crawl React component structure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to draw a tree view of my app (leaf for each component and relationships between them) but Im unable to find a way to crawl the structure.

If you `console.log(this)` in root component, you'll get plenty of data but Fiber and other latest additions have made everything a bit trickier.

I was unable to find any reliable paths to child components. I could try to climb from bottom to up but how would that exactly work? Besides figuring out how, app brances to many different directions, I couldn't just start from one component.

You can find [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/hacv3u5k/).

How to crawl React app component structure?

Comment: I'd suggest checking out the react-devtools repo and seeing how they do it. https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools

Comment: What's the purpose? Debugging?

Comment: @estus Something like that. App is getting big and starting to getting tricky to keep whole structure in my head at once (when I need it). React devtools is great for some things but I'd prefer tree view for other things (e.g figuring out best places to use `shouldComponentUpdate`).

Comment: Then you need to do something like React Devtools did. Since the approach is cumbersome and your complaints are aimed at Devtools UI, I guess it would be efficient to fork Devtools instead of building your own from scratch. See also https://github.com/bruderstein/react-render-hook for simpler implementation.

Comment: @estus Not sure we're thinking the same thing. I don't want anything nearly as complex as devtools, just iterate over components and render `div` with component name, no live updates, props, etc. I'll look into `render-hook` but I have a feeling that it has similar base architecture to devtools.

Comment: *and render div with component name, no live updates, props, etc.* - you will likely find in the middle of doing that that you need live updates, because components may render asynchronously. Also, async rendering in React 17 will make this even more complicated. So I would suggest to reuse the logic behind Devtools and focus on different UI implementation.